# combinatrix & probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

probabilities have always been something tough to comprehend for me, may be someone can help me on this. So here's the problem:

Bob tosses a coin but can't see the result, his friend John can see it, but chooses to tell the result totally at random.

What the probability that john gives a correct result ? (there are 4 distinct events) 25% ?

Is this problem different from the probability of having two consecutive tail or heads ? Seems it is since in that case, the probability is conditional to having obtained a tail or head before...

But it seems also identical, in the sense that a correct result is the realisation of two identical coin toss...

Sorry if it's confusing, I'm no math guru.

cheers
-A

Comment: Please be clearer.  When you say John "chooses to tell the result totally at random" do you mean with probability 0.5 he decides whether to keep silent or correctly announce the result of the coin toss?  Or that he always reports an answer, but with probability 0.5 he is honest or deceitful?  In the former case, your answer is 75%:  Half of the total cases Bob relays John's correct announcement, and in the remaining half of cases he has a 50% chance of being right.

Comment: like he can tell the truth or lie, at random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $4$ distinct events are:

- John sees "head" and says "head"
- John sees "head" and says "tail"
- John sees "tail" and says "head"
- John sees "tail" and says "tail"

John gives a correct result in $2$ out of $4$ events, so the probability for that is $\frac24$.

This is indeed equivalent to the probability of having $2$ heads or $2$ tails out of $2$ attempts.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. But why can't I understand it .... The first formulation those two events are totally unrelated (even if our interpretation of the result artificially relates them). On the second one (consecutive H or T) they are explicitly related. uuhhaaa..

Comment: @Alex: What makes you think they are related? The outcome of the first toss has no effect on the second toss (and hence on the outcome of that toss).

Comment: because the realisation of two H, happens if and only if given a H, the previous toss was also H... may be I'm making this thing more complex than it is.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in thinking of it as a second coin toss. It’s like this. If the second person also has a coin in his hand, what are the probabilities of both coins matching, just rephrased as a coin in his head, hence the random choice of his to say head or tails. And they are related because the final outcome is decided by the combination of both outcomes